# EmberJS parsing data from RESTful api

Tags: ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I keep studying and learning every day. And as a challenge, I'm having great difficulty getting data from the RESTful API pokeapi.co
I want to get the names and url of the results https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/
to then pass the ID as a parameter and get all data in https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ /2 /3 etc.

I'm stuck, please help me.... 
My Code:

> adapter/pokemon.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host:'https://pokeapi.co',
    namespace: 'api/v2',

    pathForType(){
        return 'pokemon';
    }
});
```

> model/pokemon.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});
```

> routes/pokemon.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model(){
        return this.store.findAll('pokemon')
//    setupController(controller, model){
//    controller.set('pokemons',model);
    }
});
```

> serializer/pokemon.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType){
        payload = {
            pokemon: payload
        },
        console.log(payload);
        return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
   }
});
```

> templates/pokemon.hbs

```
{{#each model as |pokemon|}}
      <div class="md-list-item-text">
         <h3>#{{pokemon.id}}: {{pokemon.name}}</h3>
        </div>
{{/each}}
```

Console:

```
{…}
pokemon: {…}
count: 949
next: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20&offset=20"
previous: null
results: […]
0: {…}
name: "bulbasaur"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/"
__proto__: Object { … }
1: {…}
name: "ivysaur"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2/"
__proto__: Object { … }
2: {…}
name: "venusaur"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/"
__proto__: Object { … }
3: {…}
name: "charmander"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/4/"
__proto__: Object { … }
4: {…}
name: "charmeleon"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/5/"
__proto__: Object { … }
5: {…}
name: "charizard"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/6/"
__proto__: Object { … }
6: {…}
name: "squirtle"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/7/"
__proto__: Object { … }
7: {…}
name: "wartortle"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/8/"
__proto__: Object { … }
8: {…}
name: "blastoise"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/9/"
__proto__: Object { … }
9: {…}
name: "caterpie"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10/"
__proto__: Object { … }
10: {…}
name: "metapod"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"
__proto__: Object { … }
11: {…}
name: "butterfree"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/12/"
__proto__: Object { … }
12: {…}
name: "weedle"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/13/"
__proto__: Object { … }
13: {…}
name: "kakuna"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/14/"
__proto__: Object { … }
14: {…}
name: "beedrill"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/15/"
__proto__: Object { … }
15: {…}
name: "pidgey"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/16/"
__proto__: Object { … }
16: {…}
name: "pidgeotto"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/17/"
__proto__: Object { … }
17: {…}
name: "pidgeot"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/18/"
__proto__: Object { … }
18: {…}
name: "rattata"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/19/"
__proto__: Object { … }
19: {…}
name: "raticate"
url: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20/"
__proto__: Object { … }
length: 20
Error while processing route: pokemon Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for pokemon in an object passed to 'push'
```

Comment: Can you add what parts are 'working' and what specific things are happening along the way?

Comment: Another question... will Ember know the plural and singular of 'pokemon' ? - you might want to make things 'monster' and 'monsters' or something.

Comment: `findRecord` requires id to be passed. refer https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.Store/methods/findRecord?anchor=findRecord

Comment: Added the console log and error at end. in route is findAll... sorry for my mistake

Comment: I tried... but I have to work now. : )   maybe this will help: https://ember-twiddle.com/a36f22277b81f70dfc2c19259b96f76d?openFiles=routes.monsters.monster-detail.js%2C

Comment: Worked :)
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You got it all working? I couldn't get the params correct. If you fixed the fiddle, post it. Otherwise - glad it helped. : 0  - you should post an answer.

Comment: I bet you would like this series: https://www.emberscreencasts.com/posts/96-ember-data-20-getting-started-and-basics-of-dsmodel  (I'd stick to #96 and newer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a36f22277b81f70dfc2c19259b96f76d?openFiles=routes.monsters.monster-detail.js%2C) that the sheriffderek posted and re-worked all the code.
Now it's working :)

> // app/adapters/monster.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host:'https://pokeapi.co',
  namespace: 'api/v2',

  pathForType() {
    return 'pokemon';
  },
});
```

> // app/models/monster.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  number: computed('url', function() {
    var fullUrl = this.get('url');
    return fullUrl.split('/')[6];
  }),
  name: DS.attr(),
  url: DS.attr(),
});
```

> // app/routes/monster/monster-detail.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
  model(params) { 
    var monster = this.store.findRecord('monster', params.number);
    console.info('incomming monster', monster);
    return monster;
  }
});
```

> // app/serializers/monster.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'url', 

  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = {
      monster: payload.results,
    }
    console.log(payload);
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType);
  }
});
```

> {{!-- app/templates/monsters/monster-list.hbs --}}

```
<h2>/pokemon-list</h2>

<ul class='monster-list'>
  {{#each model as |monster|}}
    <li>
      #:{{monster.number}} Pokemon:{{monster.name}} - 
     </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: So, what is the story behind showing a regular URL for the monster vs an in-app ember link-to helper?

Comment: The <a href> is just for nothing ... I will (try) show the stats, moves etc of each monters in monster-details, monster-moves, etc...And thank you for emberscreencasts

Comment: If you look into https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/ you will see more data of pokemon.